# Why does QuickCheck take a long time when testing a Functor instance with a specific type signature?

Tags: performance, haskell, quickcheck

I'm working through the wonderful [Haskell Book](https://haskellbook.com/). While solving some exercises I ran QuickCheck test that took a relatively long time to run and I can't figure out why.

The exercise I am solving is in Chapter 16 - I need to write a `Functor` instance for

```hs
data Parappa f g a = 
  DaWrappa (f a) (g a)
```

Here is [a link to the full code](https://github.com/javinor/haskell-book/blob/main/ch16/SlowQuickCheck.hs) of my solution. The part I think is relevant is this:

```hs
functorCompose' :: (Eq (f c), Functor f) 
                => Fun a b -> Fun b c -> f a -> Bool
functorCompose' fab gbc x =
  (fmap g (fmap f x)) == (fmap (g . f) x)
  where f = applyFun fab
        g = applyFun gbc

type ParappaComp = 
     Fun Integer String 
  -> Fun String [Bool] 
  -> Parappa [] Maybe Integer
  -- -> Parappa (Either Char) Maybe Integer
  -> Bool


main :: IO ()
main = do
  quickCheck (functorCompose' :: ParappaComp)
```

When I run this in the REPL it takes ~6 seconds to complete. If I change `ParappaComp` to use `Either Char` instead of `[]` (see comment in code), it finishes instantaneously like I'm used to seeing in all other exercises.

I suspect that maybe QuickCheck is using very long lists causing the test to take a long time, but I am not familiar enough with the environment to debug this or to test this hypothesis.

1. Why does this take so long?
2. How should I go about debugging this?

Comment: `[]` is a *list*. An arbitrary list can have an arbitrary number of elements, so that means it can take some time to perform a mapping over the entire list. For an `Either`, this is a *single* element.

Comment: It also looks like arbitrary `Fun`s that accept lists, including `String`s, are very slow.  Switch your intermediate type from `String` to `Char`, and it completes quickly.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr, I tried that out and you're right! Can you elaborate on how you found out?

Comment: No special insight -- I just fiddled around with your example for bit and discovered that `String` was the problem.  I then tested `Fun`s with list arguments in isolation and saw that they performed quite poorly.

Answer (score 3):

> I suspect that maybe QuickCheck is using very long lists causing the test to take a long time, but I am not familiar enough with the environment to debug this or to test this hypothesis.

I'm not sure of the actual cause either, but **one way to start debugging this** is to use the `collect` function from QuickCheck to collect statistics about test cases. To start, you can collect the size of the result.

- A simple way to obtain a size is by using the `length` function, requiring the functor `f` to be `Foldable`
- You will need to implement or derive `Foldable` for `Parappa` (add `{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}` at the top of the file, add `deriving Foldable` to `Parappa`)
- To use `collect`, you need to generalize `Bool` to `Property` (in the signature of `functorCompose'` and in the type synonym `ParappaComp`)

```hs
functorCompose' :: (Eq (f c), Functor f, Foldable f) 
               => Fun a b -> Fun b c -> f a -> Property
functorCompose' fab gbc x =
  collect (length x) $
    (fmap g (fmap f x)) == (fmap (g . f) x)
  where f = applyFun fab
        g = applyFun gbc
```

With that you can see that the distribution of the lengths of generated lists is clustered around 20, with a long tail up to 100. That alone doesn't seem to explain the slowness, as one would expect that traversing lists of that size should be virtually instantaneous.